# Android MediaSession required api 21 current min is 16?

Tags: java, android

Hello friend i am new in android using media session for control media player in background but  it told me call require api level 21 current min is 16 please help how fixed this  my min sdk is 16 and target sdk is 28

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fs5T.png)

Comment: in your gradle file change minSdkVersion to 21

Comment: but i want to make compitiable with all device

Comment: `MediaSession` was added in API 21. If you will run your app in API lover than 21, and try to use `MediaSession` your app will crash. That's what this message means. Either don't use `MediaSession` or set your min SDK to 21

Comment: Actually i am creating mp3 player i want controll from background i found many resource but solution is not found last i get code from this site https://www.binpress.com/android-media-style-notifications-media-session-controls/